# Copy a section of bi dimensional onto itself

Tags: c++, c, multidimensional-array, memcpy

I have a bi dimensional boolean (integer) array, such as the following:

```
0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
```

Let's say I want to copy the first 2 by 2 section

```
0 1
0 0
```

Onto the three remaining quadrants so it'd look like the following in the end:

```
0 1 0 1
0 0 0 0
0 1 0 1
0 0 0 0
```

I'd like to use `memcpy` since I believe it is the fastest approach. How could I make use of it in this case? Is it even possible to copy bi dimensional contents?

If not, then my only change is to have a one-dimensional array where I index by N * N?

Comment: Well for this case(_maybe for this only_)  , copy `0` to first and third column and copy `1` to second and fourth . For `N*N` do it odd even columns.

Comment: That would work yeah, but I need a more general solution. I'll edit the question to make it more clear about that.

Comment: And which language are you using? Choose _one_.

Answer (score 0):

Multidimensional arrays are going to have the same layout in memory as one longer array. In either case, `memcpy` won't help you here (a single call, anyway).

```
01010000
01010000
00000000
00000000
```

Although in an abstract layout, it looks like you can just copy that square, in reality it looks like:

```
01000000010000000000000000000000
^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You would have to include all the values on the first line too.

Additionally, `memcpy` can only copy as much as the length of the source array. You can't copy 4 bytes onto 16 bytes with a single `memcpy` call.

Edit: While I was writing this, the question was edited to change the values. However, I think my point is illustrated better with the original setup. It would only coincidentally work when the pattern is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Remember

> premature optimization is the root of all evil

Write readable code and when application won't be effective enough then profile it and you'll see where you've bottlenecks but at this point I'm almost sure that you didn't use memcpy won't affect as much as you think it'll.

But..

You tagged C++ so here's my simple compileable C++ example implementation. 
It copy submatrix to the end of matrix (not before, so if you'll pass starting point of that submatrix e.g. 2,3 it wont copy it to 0,0)

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <iterator>
    #include <algorithm>

    using namespace std;

    void copy_submatrix( size_t n, 
                         size_t m, 
                         const pair<size_t, size_t> &from, 
                         const pair<size_t, size_t> &to, 
                         vector<vector<int>> &oryginal_matrix )
    {
        auto begin_y = oryginal_matrix.begin() + from.first;
        auto begin_to_y = oryginal_matrix.begin() + to.first;
        auto end_y = begin_y + m;


        for( ; begin_y != end_y; ++begin_y, ++begin_to_y )
        {
            auto begin_x = (*begin_y).begin() + from.second;
            auto begin_to_x = (*begin_to_y).begin() + to.second;

            copy( begin_x, begin_x + n, begin_to_x );
        }
    }

    void process_matrix( vector<vector<int>> &matrix, 
                         size_t submatrix_n, 
                         size_t submatrix_m )
    {
        for( size_t y = 0; y < matrix.size(); y += submatrix_m )
            for( size_t x = 0; x < matrix.size(); x += submatrix_n )
                copy_submatrix( submatrix_n,
                                submatrix_m,
                                { 0, 0 },
                                { y, x },
                                matrix );
    }

    void print( const vector<vector<int>> &matrix )
    {
        for( const auto &v : matrix )
        {
            copy( v.begin(),
                  v.end(),
                  ostream_iterator<int>( cout, " " ) );

            cout << "\n";
        }
    }

    int main() {
        vector<vector<int>> matrix{ 
            { 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 }, 
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, 
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, 
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, 
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }
        };


        cout<<"before: \n";
        print( matrix );

        process_matrix( matrix, 2, 3 );

        cout << "after: \n";
        print( matrix );

        return 0;
    }
```